# Unlink file but the file remains (Mac os Mountain Lion)

Tags: php, macos

I have a php script that I delete a file using unlink (). when launched the script files are still present in my folder, but are "empty" ... if I restart the finder these files are no longer present in the folder ...

i use osx 10.8.4, MAMP 2.1.4, php Version  5.4.10

Then if i do:

```
unlink($file);
$filecount = count(glob($mydir));

$filecount = 1;
```

**UPDATE**
my mistake about filecount :), but because it is always present in my finder?

Comment: What's the return value of the call to `unlink()` ? Are you seeing any warning ?

Comment: what is the output of `var_dump(unlink($file));` ?

Comment: with var_dump(unlink($file)); i see the correct path of image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

glob of an empty dir returns false, then
count(false) == 1 :D

Comment: oops my mistake :), but because it is always present in my finder?

Answer (score 1):

Glob return value is an array containing the matched files/directories, an empty array if no file matched or FALSE on error.

Comment: oops my mistake :), but because it is always present in my finder?